# Cannot find -1dwmapi error: 1d returned 1 exit status on CodeBlocks, basic GCC application

Tags: c, gcc, gtk3, msys2

I am working on my college project.
I am new to GCC, GTK and all related stuff.
I have successfully installed GTK on Windows 10 via MSYS2.
I have followed this tutorial:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUJFYOCbuDg
```

In the next part of tutorial,
I am using Codeblocks (as discussed in the tutorial):

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlwWKzJFNqo&ab_channel=MichaelB.
```

When I copy paste this code in main.c in my project GTK3_Demo

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static int counter = 0;

void greet(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    // printf equivalent in GTK+
    g_print("Welcome to GTK\n");
    g_print("%s clicked %d times\n",
            (char*)data, ++counter);
}

void destroy(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* button;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
                    G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);
    /* Let's set the border width of the window to 20.
    * You may play with the value and see the
    * difference. */
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 20);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Click Me!");

    g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button),
                    "clicked", G_CALLBACK(greet),
                    "button");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I get following error :

```
||=== Build: Debug in GTK3_Demo (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\raman\Documents\GTK3_Demo\main.c||In function 'activate':|
C:\Users\raman\Documents\GTK3_Demo\main.c|23|warning: implicit declaration of function 'gtk_window_set_child' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
ld.exe||cannot find -ldwmapi|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: FYI, that's `ld` and `-ldwmapi` (L, not 1).

Comment: The tutorial looks ok. Maybe you have more than one MinGW version installed? The one from MSYS2 and the one that comes with CB, perhaps? Uninstall the CB MinGW and configure CB to use the MSYS2.

Comment: Thank you !!Yes you are right.. i have done the same.. i m uninstalling everything and starting with the tutorial again

Comment: Yes thankyou @HolyBlackCat, everything is working properly now !